# Sharepoint 2013 PowerShell and localization

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Here is my problem:

I have a US server with language pack installed.
I created a site collection in french.
I localized my feature that creates new content types.
If I activate my feature via the site collection (Web), my content types are in french.
If I activate my feature via PowerShell, my content types are in english.

I want to be able to activate my features via Powershell and have the right language used. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the examples I found on the Sharepoint server, it's not recommended to define displayname of fields in the content type itself... so got it working

Comment: Hi David, I'm in the same situation but I've not defined any display name in the content type. I have an english SharePoint farm with Arabic language pack installed. The issue is happening with SharePoint OOTB fields on an Arabic site. When I activate my feature using powershell display name is in english, and when I activate it through web, display name is in arabic. Can't find any explanation. Anyone could enlighten me ?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you. If i remember well I only had this problem when defining display name in the content types.